# What is the probability that no married couples are among the chosen?

Tags: probability

Eight married couples are standing in a room.

4 people are randomly chosen.

What is the probability that no married couples are among the chosen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to figure this out would be to choose 4 different married couples to provide a chosen person (there are $\left(\begin{array}{c} 8\\ 4\end{array}\right)=70$ ways to do this).  Then pick one member of each of the 4 chosen couples (there are $2^4=16$ ways to do this).  So altogther there are $70\cdot 16=1120$ ways to choose 4 people so that no two are married to each other.

So the probability of none married to each other among the 4 chosen is
$\frac{1120}{\left(\begin{array}{c} 16\\ 4\end{array}\right)}=\frac{1120}{1820}=\frac8{13}$.

So same as John's answer, just a different approach to counting in the problem.

Comment: Nitpick: the denominator at the end should be ${16 \choose 4}$. But this is very nice! I couldn't see how to count the $1120$ combinations directly.

Comment: Good catch.  I knew that about the 16 not 8.

Comment: Thanks guys :) John's answer helped me really understand the problem but I had to accept this method because it's the most efficient.

Comment: @StephanCasey Glad my answer helped. I think all five answers solve the problem a bit differently, and all five methods may be useful to you at some point.  More tools in the toolbox and all that.

Answer (score 5):

To get the probability, you'll need

- the total number of combinations of $16$ people taken $4$ at a time, and
- the total number of those combinations that have no married couples among them.

You have the first part:  ${16 \choose 4}$.

Rather than count up the number of combinations for the second part directly, you can count the complement, and subtract from the total.

So if you *do* have at least one married couple in the chosen, you can have one couple, or two.

If you have two married couples in the chosen group, then there are ${8 \choose 2}$ possible combinations.

If you have (exactly) one married couple, first you pick the married couple in the group: ${8 \choose 1}$.  Now, from the remaining $14$ people, you pick two that aren't married to each other.  So pick the two couples that you're going to draw from -- ${7 \choose 2}$ -- and then pick the particular spouse from each one -- ${2 \choose 1} \cdot {2 \choose 1}$.

Now, you subtract the number of combinations that *do* have *at least one* married couple from the total number of combinations to get the number of combinations that have *no* married couples.  This gives as your probability:

$$P = \frac{{16 \choose 4} - {8 \choose 2} - {8 \choose 1}{7 \choose 2}{2 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1}}{{16 \choose 4}} = \frac{8}{13} \approx 0.61538.$$

Answer (score 2):

Start by choosing a person. Then choose a second. The probability that it is not a partner of the first is $\frac{14}{15}$. Suppose that this is indeed the case and choose a third. In that case the probability that it is not a partner of one of the two that are allready chosen is $\frac{12}{14}$. Suppose again that this is indeed the case and finally choose the fourth. In that case the probability that it is not a partner of one of the three that are allready chosen is $\frac{10}{13}$.

This leads to a probability of $$\frac{14}{15}\times \frac{12}{14}\times \frac{10}{13}=\frac{8}{13}$$

---

The same principle in a more formal jacket:

Choose persons one by one.

For $n\in\left\{ 1,2,3,4\right\} $ define
$X_{n}$ as the number of married couples under the first $n$ persons
that are chosen.

If $n$ persons have been chosen in such a way that $X_n=0$ then $16-n$ are left and among them there are exactly $16-2n$ that are not partner of one that is
allready chosen.

So: $$P\left\{ X_{n+1}=0\mid X_{n}=0\right\} =\frac{16-2n}{16-n}$$ and, since $X_{n+1}=0\Rightarrow X_n=0$, consequently: $$P\left\{ X_{n+1}=0\right\} =\frac{16-2n}{16-n}P\left\{ X_{n}=0\right\} $$ 
leading to:

$$P\left\{ X_{4}=0\right\} =\frac{10}{13}P\left\{ X_{3}=0\right\} =\frac{10}{13}\frac{12}{14}P\left\{ X_{2}=0\right\} =\frac{10}{13}\frac{12}{14}\frac{14}{15}P\left\{ X_{1}=0\right\} =\frac{10}{13}\frac{12}{14}\frac{14}{15}=\frac{8}{13}$$

Answer (score 1):

For no married couples: choose 4 from the 8 available couples, considering that within each couple, we can have either one of the two partners.

$\binom{8}{4} \times 2^4$

Now divide this by the total number of selections we can make from 16 people:

$$\frac{\binom{8}{4} \times 2^4}{\binom{16}{4}} = \frac{8}{13} \approx 0.6154 $$

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet one more way of getting the answer.  The number of ways of making a selection with $m$ men and $4-m$ women that avoid married couples is ${8\choose m}{8-m\choose4-m}$.  The requested probability is therefore

$${{8\choose4}{8\choose0}+{8\choose3}{5\choose1}+{8\choose2}{6\choose2}+{8\choose1}{7\choose3}+{8\choose0}{8\choose4}\over{16\choose4}}={1120\over1820}={8\over13}$$

Answer (score 1):

Very easy way to do this is to think of it as the following:
you have 8 couples, which means 16 members,
since you have to pick 4 people that are not married
you have the following possibilities: 16 * 14 * 12 * 10
this is because when you select the first person, you can't take its lover.
now you can compute the probability easily as 16 * 14 * 12 * 10 / 16 * 15 * 14 *13 = 8/13

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).